# What are the criteria for determining the 'clutter' on a web page?

Tags: design, usability-testing

I came across the [clutter test](http://www.websitecriteria.com/about_the_cluttertest.html) offered by websitecriteria.com while doing some research on guidelines about content readability and presentation of information on a web page.

It makes reference to an algorithm that is used to calculate the relative clutter on a web page, and considering that Google Home page has a 16% rating and that Yahoo has a 86% rating, how useful and accurate do you think this test is, and what are the main elements involved in assessing the clutter on a page? Can it be as simple as a formula, or does it require more contextual information and an understanding of the specific audience for it to be a fair assessment?

Answer (score 2):

There are two interesting papers from http://www.labinthewild.org/ that address this. They are more nuanced than just "clutter" but they seem to relate.

**Quantifying Visual Preferences Around the World**

http://reinecke.people.si.umich.edu/Publications_files/ReineckeCHI2014.pdf?bcsi_scan_edf0484211d699cd=0&bcsi_scan_filename=ReineckeCHI2014.pdf

*Website aesthetics have been recognized as an influential
moderator of people’s behavior and perception. However,
what users perceive as “good design” is subject to individual
preferences, questioning the feasibility of universal design
guidelines. To better understand how people’s visual
preferences differ, we collected 2.4 million ratings of the
visual appeal of websites from nearly 40 thousand participants
of diverse backgrounds. We address several gaps in the
knowledge about design preferences of previously understudied
groups. Among other findings, our results show that the
level of colorfulness and visual complexity at which visual
appeal is highest strongly varies: Females, for example, liked
colorful websites more than males. A high education level
generally lowers this preference for colorfulness. Russians
preferred a lower visual complexity, and Macedonians liked
highly colorful designs more than any other country in our
dataset. We contribute a computational model and estimates
of peak appeal that can be used to support rapid evaluations
of website design prototypes for specific target groups.*

**Predicting Users’ First Impressions of Website Aesthetics
With a Quantification of
Perceived Visual Complexity and Colorfulness**

http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~reinecke/Publications_files/Reinecke_CHI2013.pdf

*Users make lasting judgments about a website’s appeal within
a split second of seeing it for the first time. This first impression
is influential enough to later affect their opinions of a
site’s usability and trustworthiness. In this paper, we demonstrate
a means to predict the initial impression of aesthetics
based on perceptual models of a website’s colorfulness and
visual complexity. In an online study, we collected ratings
of colorfulness, visual complexity, and visual appeal of a set
of 450 websites from 548 volunteers. Based on these data,
we developed computational models that accurately measure
the perceived visual complexity and colorfulness of website
screenshots. In combination with demographic variables such
as a user’s education level and age, these models explain approximately
half of the variance in the ratings of aesthetic
appeal given after viewing a website for 500ms only.*

Answer (score -1):

Never trust a machine! That's why UX matters. It's not working in all themes, subjects, fields and contexts.

Not all users are acting the same. Most of the users don't look into a website generally. They always follow up a specific pattern.

For example, every time I open yahoo.com, I just look at the right side looking for sign-in button. That's because I just using my Yahoo email and nothing else. So Yahoo website isn't so much cluttered for me because I don't look at other parts.

This approach is just a general estimation. However, it doesn't mean to leave websites cluttered, you can't rely on them.